# Can't use any function after closest function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

Here is my selector

```
var phoneInputs = $("input[value^='+77']");
var inputBlock = phoneInputs.closest("div");
```

Now I have the following data in my `inputBlock`

```
<div class="intl-tel-input allow-dropdown separate-dial-code iti-sdc-2">
<div class="flag-container"><div class="selected-flag" tabindex="0" title="Russia (Россия): +7">
<div class="iti-flag ru"></div>
<div class="selected-dial-code">+7</div>
<div class="iti-arrow"></div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="text" name="sos[0][phone]" class="form-control nav-reg-phone" value="+7705 333 6916" autocomplete="off" placeholder="912 345-67-89"></div>
```

But can't use any function. For example when I do smth. like  `inputBlock.find('div.iti-flag')`, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: inputBlock .find is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:5`

Can't get what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Use $(inputBlock).find(...

Comment: :) I'm pretty sure you are not showing entire code. With what you posted - such error is not possible.

Comment: Unable to replicate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/mmkjvse7/

Comment: @Roy: `inputBlock` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: @Roy And if it still doesn't work (which will not) OP should try `$($($($($($(inputBlock)))))).find` :D

Comment: the code should work check the jsfiddle posted by david

Comment: Must be a problem in some code you haven't supplied. What browser? What jQuery version?

Comment: Here is my entire code: `var phoneInputs = $("input[value^='+77']");
            if($(phoneInputs.length > 0)){
                for(var ind in phoneInputs){
                    if(phoneInputs.hasOwnProperty(ind)){
                        phoneInputs[ind].closest("div").find("div.iti-flag").removeClass('ru').addClass('kz');
                    }
                }
            }`

Comment: So, I was trying to call "find" function for each element, not for object. Now it is working fine. Corrected code: `phoneInputs.closest("div").find("div.iti-flag").removeClass('ru').addClass('kz');`